# Access, Opening the Same Form in Different ways using Buttons

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm using Access 2007 at work and trying to build a database.  I'd like to know if it's possible to have two different buttons on the "Main Menu" form that open the same "Data Entry" form.  BUT, one button automatically goes to a new blank record for data entry, and the other button prompts the user to enter a specific ID # (tied to a field in the form) and then the form will open on that record.  This would be for updating that specific record.

Is this possible?  I am a beginner with VBA code.  If this is possible with later versions of Access but not 2007, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two buttons on the form. Let us name them as **addRecBtn** and **openRecBtn** let us say the form you are trying to open is tmpFrmName. So the first button will open the form in Data Entry Mode, the second one will open the form in normal edit mode.

The code should be something like,

```
Private Sub addRecBtn_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "tmpFrmName", DataMode:=acFormAdd
End Sub
```

The second form will first have to get the number you are trying to open, for example let us call it the numberID. So your code would be.

```
Private Sub openRecBtn_Click()
    Dim numID As Long

    numID = InputBox("Please enter the ID : ")

    If DCount("*", "yourTable", "numberID = " & numID) <> 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "tmpFrmName", WhereCondition:="numberID = " & numID
    Else
        MsgBox "The numberID : " & numID & " does not exist, please try again !"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: first off thanks!!! This is mostly working but when i enter in the number for a record, it comes up with a blank record to add new data into.  I need it to recall the existing record tied to that number so that i can add new data to that record.  I'm so close!

Comment: Include the *WhereCondition* option with `OpenForm` to target the selected ID.

Comment: YES!!!! Looks like it's working perfectly.  Thanks so much, everyone, this is the best forum ever.

Comment: Yes, +1 from me.  Be aware of `InputBox()` though.  It always returns a string value.  Implicitly converting that string to a Long will work when the user inputs only digits.  However if the user inputs something else, like "Surprise!", clicks OK without entering anything, or clicks Cancel, your code will throw a type mismatch error.

Comment: @HansUp, absolutely true. I was thinking of writing a bit more robust code, but by the time I finished compiling, I saw that this could be a start, and if the OP needed more robust code, it is possible. So I left it at that. I also saw that your method of using Form controls were also a sure thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `DoCmd.OpenForm` with different options to accomplish both your goals.

1. *"one button automatically goes to a new blank record for data entry"*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="YourForm", View:=acNormal, DataMode:=acFormAdd
```

2. *"the other button prompts the user to enter a specific ID # (tied to a field in the form) and then the form will open on that record"*

```vb
Dim strWhere As String
strWhere = "[id]=" & Me.txtId
Debug.Print strWhere ' <- inspect this in the Immediate window
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="YourForm", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition=strWhere
```

The first form includes a text box named *txtId*, which contains the ID value you want to make current in the second form (*YourForm*).

Comment: sorry just to clarify, txtId can be replaced by a field name already in the form?  I also don't get the "immediate window"

Comment: Yes, I intended *txtID* to be a text box on "Main Form" for the user to enter her ID selection.  If you prefer `InputBox()` as Paul suggested, use that instead.

Comment: Immediate window is the VB Editor feature where you can view the output from `Debug.Print`, inspect values in VBA break mode, test VBA statements, etc.  It will be useful for you to become familiar with it.  You can use Ctrl+g to go there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

My advice would be to do it with several functions - put the "shared" functionality in one (eg open the form), and then for the differences, make two functions which call the shared one

eg

```
function openForm()
{
    //Do open form stuff
}

function promptForID()
{
    openForm();
    //Do stuff that prompts for ID
}

function blankRecord()
{
    openForm();
    //Do stuff that sets up a blank record
}
```